# Java- when a user inputs a string, is it a string literal?

Tags: java, string-literals

I have a question to help me with homework. We were to write a program using a string literal and print it in reverse.  I wrote it and it works fine but i have two different versions. The first uses the scanner so the user can input a string and then it prints in reverse. In the second, i declare a string literal and just print that in reverse.

My question isn't about my program which works fine, but rather i can't find anywhere online or in my book which says an inputted string is a string literal.  I understand that a string literal is usually written as

```
String a = "Welcome to Java"
```

but can be written as

```
String a = new String("Welcome to Java")
```

- So then is an inputted string not the same as a string literal?
- Does it have to be written out in quotes to be considered a string literal?

I'm assuming the answer will be yes since my book basically says it has to be in quotes, but i want to double check before i hand in my assignment that i'm turning in the correct version. Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Answer (score 7):

A string literal is one that is in quotes and literally in your code:

```
String literal = "string literal";
```

An input string is not a string literal, just a string.

Answer (score 3):

At @Shakedown implies, a string literal is a syntactic element of your Java source code.  It is also (in a loose sense) a Java `String` object that *corresponds* to that literal when your program is executed.  We can say that the literal *denotes* the runtime string.  Furthermore, the JLS specifies that two string literals with the same characters will denote the same String object in the context of a simple program execution.

In your code snippets.

```
String a = "Welcome to Java";
```

and

```
String a = new String("Welcome to Java");
```

... the `"Welcome to Java"` character sequences in the source code are both String literals, and assuming that they are used in the same execution, they will denote the same (interned) String object.

However, `new String("Welcome to Java")` is not a String literal.   It is an expression that creates a new `String` object.  And the result of executing that expression is *guaranteed* to be a *different* `String` object to the one that the literal(s) denoted.

---

> Does it have to be written out in quotes to be considered a string literal?

Yes.  And more than that, it has to be written in quotes *in your program's source code* to qualify as a string literal.

If I wrote a program that accepted use input from a GUI, and the user entered input with double quote characters around it, that is NOT a string literal.  Rather it is a `String` which happens to start and end with double quote characters.  (Yes ... in this case the string's *value* would include the quote characters.)

Answer (score 1):

A string literal (`"foo bar baz"`) is a `String` object -- it's just a nice syntax for creating such objects. When you get input from the user, it will also be a `String` object -- the same type as that literal.

However, a string literal refers to that syntax (the stuff in quotes), not the type of object. So, to answer your question precisely, the user's input is not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The inputted string is no different from a string literal.

Strings are stored, in Java, as objects of class `String`. One way of getting one is a string literal: "hello sailor" is a string literal, and when used in a Java expression, it's an object of class `String`. Methods that return strings also return objects of class `String`. So they're equivalent for all purposes.

There are ways to tell a literal from a `new String("...")`, but those are rather contrived. As a beginner, you need not worry about those.